# 'int' object is not subscriptable in python

Tags: python

enemy_pos = [random.randint(0, int(Width)), 0]

this is my list and where I try to run this following function it says: 'int' object is not subscriptable

the function:

```py
def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):

    p_x = player_pos[0]
    p_y = player_pos[1]
    e_x = enemy_pos[0]
    e_y = enemy_pos[1]

    if (p_x <= e_x < (p_x + 50)) or (e_x <= p_x < (e_x + 50)):
        if (p_y <= e_y < (p_y + 50)) or (e_y <= p_y < (e_y + 50)):
            return True
    return False
```

The problem happens at the `e_x = enemy_pos[0]` line.

Comment: can't reproduce, It works on this end.  suggest printing out enemy_pos at top of function. Maybe you are sending in something else.

Comment: Your function is fine. You may assign the enemy_pos variable somewhere to an int before passing it to the function.